# China visit visa for unaccompanied child

Tags: visas, china, minors, syrian-citizens

Can my 7-year-old child get a visa to visit China with his Chinese teacher, without parents? His nationality is Syrian.

Comment: What is the intention of his visit? What are the plans for the trip?